# trying to display an image using cakephp mysql

Tags: cakephp

i am trying to display an image using cakephp and mysql..my code is running but it is not displaying an image
uploadsController is::

```html
<?php
class UploadsController extends AppController{
    var $name='Uploads';
    function share_video($stu_id=null)
    {
          $this->set('stu',$stu_id);
                $tut=$this->Session->read('tutor_id');
                $data=$this->Upload->query("select * from tutors AS Tutor where tutor_id='$tut'");
                $this->set('val1',$data);
                if (!empty($this->data)) {
     $this->Upload->create();
     if ($this->uploadFile() && $this->Upload->save($this->data))  {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The upload has been saved', true));
      //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
     } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The upload could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
     }
   }
                       $data=$this->Upload->find('all');
                        $this->set('val2',$data);
                        $this->layout='tutor';
  }
  function uploadFile() {
                    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    $file = $this->data['Upload']['file'];
             if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   //$id = String::uuid();
   if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP.'webroot/uploads'.DS.$file['name'])) {
    $this->request->data['Upload']['upload_id'] = $id;
     $this->request->data['Upload']['filename'] = $file['name'];
     $this->request->data['Upload']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
     $this->request->data['Upload']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
     return true;
   }
    }
                  
    return false;
  
            
    }
    function download($filename=null)
    {
        $data=$this->Upload->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('filename'=>$filename)));
        $this->set('val1',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

and my download.ctp file is:

Html->image('uploads/'.$val1[0]['Upload']['filename']);
//echo 'Html->url(array('controller' => 'uploads','action' => 'download',$val1[0]['Upload']['filename'])).'" width="100" height="100"/>'; 

?>

Comment: echo $this->Html->image('uploads/'.$val1['Upload']['filename'],array('class'=>'media-object img img-thumbnail','alt'=>$val1['Upload']['filename'])
      );

Comment: this code doesn't work

Comment: can you print what output come in $data;

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Upload] => Array
                (
                    [upload_id] => 1
                    [tutor_id] => 6
                    [stu_id] => 3
                    [grade] => X
                    [subject] => Maths
                    [filename] => 2014-09-29 12_19_42-Greenshot.png
                    [filesize] => 1679057
                    [filemime] => image/png
                )

        )

)     this is the output after printing $data

Comment: $data=$this->Upload->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('filename'=>$filename)));

Comment: echo $this->Html->image('uploads/'.$val1['Upload']['filename'],array('class'=>'media-‌​object img img-thumbnail','alt'=>$val1['Upload']['filename']) 
 );

Comment: the upload folder should be img/uploads/

Comment: if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT."/img/uploads/".$file['name'])) {

Comment: this code is working on my server

Comment: http://techphant.com/dope/feature/3 click on features links

Comment: its ok, please voteup below is my code

Answer (score 0):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT."/img/uploads/".$file['name']‌​)) { /* conditions*/ }

$data=$this->Upload->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('filename'=>$filenam‌​e)));

echo $this->Html->image('uploads/'.$val1['Upload']['filename'],array('class'=>'media-‌​‌​object img img-thumbnail','alt'=>$val1['Upload']['filename']) );
```